# Extension of the chain rule to multiple variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Say there is a function $F(x,y,z)$, and $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all functions of a single variable $t$. That means that $F$ is by proxy a function of a single variable $t$. Is there an extension of the chain rule to multiple variables that would make it possible to solve this without plugging in the values of $x$, $y$, and $z$?

As an example, say we have $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$, where $x=e^t$, $y=t^2$, and $z=t^3$. Is there something similar to the chain rule that would allow you to calculate $\frac{d}{dt}F(x(t),y(t),z(t))$? I know it's a trivial example and it would be easy to just substitute the values of $x$, $y$, and $z$ into $F(x,y,z)$, but I just chose this at random so that I could see how it is done through example.

Comment: See [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Look up the chain rule. It will tell you that
$$\frac d{dt} F(\vec x(t)) = \nabla F(\vec x(t))\cdot \frac{d\vec x(t)}{dt}.$$